# Is there a way to set a default send account on Gmail?

Tags: gmail

So I've decided to try the Gmail app again for email. I really like it, bar one thing.

I cannot seem to specify a default send account. Every time I create an email, it sets it as gmail. I do use Gmail quite a lot, but I also use 2 other accounts frequently.

Is there a way to specify the default send account from the android app (similar to the web client?).

Comment: As far as I can tell, no there is no way.  I would put it as an answer, but I can't confirm that 100%.

Comment: Yeah, I'm finding lots of sneaky things google does (such as always having your gmail inbox, rather than all inboxes being the default) to get you to use gmail as a primary account. Just was checking in case there was something newer than the years old articles I'd been reading.